# Picasa using common linux/windows store

Tags: windows, linux, picasa

I'd like to use the same index of images from Picasa under Windows and Linux (so that albums, tags, "uploaded" marks are in sync). Is it described anywhere and is it relatively safe to try? Or should I just keep separate indexes...